# How to print all words with a specific length and a multiplication of that length

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to print all the given words in the array, if I type in a number above 2. And if I give for example the number 4, it should also print the length of the words with the multipcation of 4, so it should print:

- words with the length 4
  -words with the length 8
  etc.

I'm facing problems with ^ that part of my code.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordsInReverseOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();


        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();

        while (!(word.equals("STOP"))) {
            words.add(word);
            System.out.println("Type a word: ");
            word = reader.nextLine();
        }

        if (word.equals("STOP"))
            for (String print : words)
                System.out.println(print);

        System.out.println("Give a number: ");
        int number = reader.nextInt();

        while (number < 2) {
            System.out.println("Give a number: ");
            number = reader.nextInt();
        }


        if (2 < number)
            for (int i = number; word.length() == i; i = number * number) {
                for (String printer : words)
                    System.out.println(printer);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last part with

```
words.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length));       

if (2 < number) {
    int limit = number;
    for (String w : words) {
        if (w.length() > limit) {
            limit += number;
        }      
        if (w.length() == limit) {
            System.out.println(w);
        }
    }
}
```

Sort the words based on length and loop over the word array comparing the word length with `number` or a multiplier of number that increases every time a longer word is found.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the code works for the given numbers, but not for the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you would need to iterate over the words collection and then you would need to check each word's length if it's a multiple of your desired length. Just some pseudo code here, because my Java is a bit rusty. I'm sure you can translate this to Java.

```
for each (word in words){
    if (word.length mod length == 0)
        print(word)
}
```

Where `a mod b` is the modulo operator, is the remainder of the integer division `a/b`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the code works for the given numbers, but not for the multiplication.

Comment: Not sure, what you mean by your comment, but this pseudo code surely prints all words whichs length is a multiple of the given number.